# What is wrong why am I getting nothing?

Tags: python, kivy

```
def W():
  print("deleting")
  [f.unlink() for f in Path("../Image-Loader-V20/IMG").glob("*") if f.is_file()] 
  [f.unlink() for f in Path("../Image-Loader-V20/TXT").glob("*") if f.is_file()] 
  pass


Clock.schedule_interval(W, 10.0)
```

I am trying to delete the contents of a file every hour but here i put 10 seconds but when I run it nothing happens which is kinda weird does anyone know what is happenening? Like the files do delete with the function but the thing just dont work...

I tried it with () next to W but that neither

Comment: Just a heads up that your use of comprehensions here is frowned on.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Answer (score 0):

In `kivi` docs it's said, that you should use e.g. lambda to schedule a function which does not take any arguments (and that looks like your case):

```py
def no_args_func():
    print("I accept no arguments, so don't schedule me in the clock")

Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: no_args_func(), 0.5)
```

Source: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html

So assuming your function works on its own (which you said and I didn't check) your code would be:

```py
def W():
  print("deleting")
  [f.unlink() for f in Path("../Image-Loader-V20/IMG").glob("*") if f.is_file()] 
  [f.unlink() for f in Path("../Image-Loader-V20/TXT").glob("*") if f.is_file()] 
  pass


Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt:W(), 10.0)
```